# Pointers in AVL Tree Rotation

Tags: java, avl-tree, tree-rotation

I have trouble understanding why the below tree rotation code works. If `T2` points to `y.left` and `y.left` points to `x`, doesn't this make the last assignment `x.right = T2` equal to `x.right = x`? Shouldn't the pointer point to the initial `T2`?

```
Node leftRotate(Node x) {
    Node y = x.right;
    Node T2 = y.left;

    // Perform rotation
    y.left = x;
    x.right = T2;

    //  Update heights
    x.height = max(height(x.left), height(x.right)) + 1;
    y.height = max(height(y.left), height(y.right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node T2 = y.left;
```

This line makes `T2` point to the same place `y.left` pointed *at the time that line was run.*  If `y.left` is updated to point to a different object -- `x`, in this case -- that change is *not* reflected in `T2`.

Mind you, if someone changed a *property* of that object, *that* change would be reflected.  E.g. the code

```
Node T2 = y.left;
y.left.foo = bar;
```

then `T2.foo` would reflect the change to `bar`.  It's changes to what `y.left` is *referencing* that aren't reflected.  This is a pretty universal thing in Java, related to the whole "references are passed by value" thing.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to reason with this is to draw it out and go through it a step at a time:

At the beginning of the function we have Node x:

```
   x
  /  \
 L    R
     /   \
    l1    r1
```

Now we say y = R.

```
  R
 /  \
L1   R1
```

Node T2 = R.Left which is l2

Then the rotation:

y.left (R1.Left) = x

```
     R
   /   \
  x      R1
 / \
l   R
   /  \
  l1    r1
```

x.right = T2 (l1)

```
    R
   /  \
  x    r1
 / \
l   l1
```

A great resource I found for all things tries (albeit in C) is [eternally confuzzled](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_avl.aspx)